# Vue 3 + Store is not defined Vuex v4.0.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuex

I am trying to access my store ($store) variable by importing it from the file
`import store from "../store"`
but it I am getting this error while `console.log(store)`:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: store is not defined
    at eval (eval at _callee$ (functions.services.js:1:1), <anonymous>:1:1)
    at _callee$ (functions.services.js?5215:46:1)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js?96cf:63:1)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js?96cf:294:1)
    at Generator.eval [as next] (runtime.js?96cf:119:1)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:3:1)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:25:1)
    at eval (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:32:1)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at eval (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:21:1)
eval @ VM388:1
_callee$ @ functions.services.js?5215:46
tryCatch @ runtime.js?96cf:63
invoke @ runtime.js?96cf:294
eval @ runtime.js?96cf:119
asyncGeneratorStep @ asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:3
_next @ asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:25
eval @ asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:32
eval @ asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:21
eval @ functions.services.js?5215:42
fetchF @ functions.services.js?5215:42
login @ SignIn.vue?c790:92
eval @ SignIn.vue?c790:49
eval @ runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js?830f:1457
callWithErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:6737
callWithAsyncErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:6746
invoker @ runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js?830f:357
```

Here is the file where I am using it: "functions.services.js"

```
import store from "@/store"

export function fetchF(link, body, method, isTokenNeeded = true, isJSON = true) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        var access_token = getLocalStorage("access_token");
        var refresh_token = getLocalStorage("refresh_token");
        if (!(access_token == null && refresh_token == null) || isTokenNeeded == false) {
            fetch(store.serverLink + link, {
                method,
                headers: {
                    authorization: `Bearer ${access_token} ${refresh_token}`,
                    Accept: "application/json",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(body),
            }).then((response) => response[isJSON == true ? "json" : "text"]()).then(rsp => {
                setLocalStorage("access_token", rsp.access_token);
                setLocalStorage("refresh_token", rsp.refresh_token);
                resolve(rsp);
            }).catch(error => {
                setLocalStorage("access_token", "");
                setLocalStorage("refresh_token", "");
                store.dispatch("changeData", {
                    option: "alertEl",
                    value: "Please log in, and try again",
                });
                return resolve({ isSuccess: false, err: "Please log in, and try again" });
            })
        } else {
            if (!(access_token == null && refresh_token == null) && isTokenNeeded == true) {
                store.dispatch("changeData", {
                    option: "alertEl",
                    value: "Please log in, and try again",
                });
            }
            return resolve({ isSuccess: false, err: "Please log in, and try again" });
        }
    });
}
```

here is the store file "index.js":

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
var isDev = true
export const store = createStore({
  state: {
    serverLink: isDev ? "http://localhost:3000" : "http://.......:3000",
    isAuth: false,
    isInitiated: false,
    alertEl: ""
  },
  mutations: {
  },
  getters: {
    getAuthStatus: state => {
      return state.isAuth
    },
    getInitiatedStatus: state => {
      return state.isInitiated
    }

  },
  setters: {

  },
  actions: {
  },
  modules: {
  }
})
export default store;
```

I tried to use it in router.js too, for authenticating routes before entering them but the same issue happens

Comment: There is no `console.log(store)` in the code you posted. Double check that you run the code that you see and it wasn't cached. Try to rename `store` in functions.services.js to something else. In case the problem persists, try to find this code in devtools with shift+ctrl+f and check what happened with import statement there. Btw `return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {` is a terrible antipattern, `.then`, `async` and `Promise` should never be mixed like that, this will cause nothing but troubles

Comment: Yes, I found out that console.log is different than writing the name of the variable on the console (while breakpoint), it worked thank you

Comment: and for the ```store.serverLink``` it has to be transferred to ```store.state.serverLink```